# Setting a UILabel.text property causes memory leak in thread

Tags: ios, nstimer

I'm baffled!

I have a timer setup that runs a countdown, within the timer I update UILabels with the elapsed time which all works great but the strange thing is that the setting of the text causes a memory leak when I test through instruments.

The timer code is

```
NSTimer* timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.0f
                                    target:self
                                    selector:@selector(myTimer:)
                                    userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:YES];
self.pnTimer = timer;
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:self.pnTimer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

my timer method has the following...

```
- (void)myTimer:(NSTimer*)timer {
  ...
  if (self.secondsPassed <=9) {
     [self.secondsLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"0%i",self.secondsPassed]];
  } else {
     [self.secondsLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",self.secondsPassed]];
  }
  ...

}
```

Commenting out the [self.secondsLabel... lines and looking in Instruments at the #Living column, it  stays  roughly where it is but allowing the code to run and update the labels causes the #Living column to increase constantly until the app becomes sluggish and unresponsive (20 or so mins)

The label is defined as

```
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *secondsLabel;
```

Please note that I am also testing this on an iPhone 5 device using iOS 6.1

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong here?
Thanks for any help

Comment: Aw, that terrible formatting hack! Please use `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d", self.secondsPassed]` instead.

Comment: What else does -myTimer: do?

Comment: Well, apart from a self.secondsPassed--;  I have commented out everything else when I narrowed it down to updating the label.

Comment: And thanks for the %02d formatter, didn't know that existed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok found what it was.  The UI also has a glossy gradient Button UIButton+Glossy (http://www.mlsite.net/blog/?p=232).  I deleted the button and updating the labels no longer causes a memory leak.  I assume that updating the labels every second caused a full UI refresh which also updated the button which has issues of its own!

Thanks